# Validating email and user Angular2 asking to the server

Tags: angular, sails.js

I have the next logic validator, and i want to check the data, send it to the server. the server respond good, but when i try to send an user that is taken, i can send the form. Thanks.
    //file: email-user-validator.ts

```
 interface IUsernameEmailValidator {
    }
function checkUser(control: Control, source: string) : Observable<IUsernameEmailValidator> {

  // Manually inject Http
  let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
  let http = injector.get(Http);
  let body;
  if(source == 'email'){
    body = JSON.stringify({ email:  control.value })
  }else if(source == 'username'){
    body = JSON.stringify({ username:  control.value });
  }

  return new Observable((obs: any) =>{
    if(!!control.valueChanges){
      control
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .flatMap(value => http.post('/user/check', body))
        .subscribe(
          value =>{
            obs.next(null);
            obs.complete();
          },
          error => {
            if(error.status == 500) return;
            let msg = error.json().message;
            obs.next({ msg: true });
            obs.complete();
          }
        )
    }
  });
}
export class CustomValidators {
  static checkUsername(control: Control) {
    checkUser(control, 'username');
  }

  static checkEmail(control: Control) {
    checkUser(control, 'email');
  }
}
```

The component:

```
//File: main-component.ts
ngOnInit(): any{
    this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.emailValidator])],
      'password': ['', Validators.minLength(8)]
    })
  }
```

Server controller

```
check: (req, res) => {
    let find = {};
    let email = false;
    if(req.param('username')){
      find.username = req.param('username');
    }else if(req.param('email')){
      find.email = req.param('email');
      email = true;
    }
    User.findOne(find).exec((err, user) => {
      if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
      if(user && !email){
        return res.status(409).json({message: 'Username taken'});
      }else if(user && !!email){
        return res.status(409).json({message: 'Email taken'})
      }
      // not taken
      return res.status(200).json({message: !!user});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you need an asynchronous validator global to your form since it applies on both email and password:

```
ngOnInit(): any{
  this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    'email': ['',
      Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.emailValidator]),
      CustomValidators.checkUser], // <-----
    'password': ['', Validators.minLength(8)]
  })
}
```

For such valdidator, you need to return a promise to notify when the validation is done, either success or failure. In both cases, you need to resolve the promise: if successful with `null`, otherwise with an object corresponding to the error.

Moreover you can provide the http as parameter and you don't need to register on the valueChanges since the validator is trigger at each update.

```
function createCheckUser(http:Http) {
  return function(control: Control) : Promise {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email:  control.value })

    return new Promise((resolve: any) =>{
      http.post('/user/check', body))
        .subscribe(
          value =>{
            // If successful
            resolve(null);
            // If validation failed
            //resolve({email:'The email...'});
          },
          error => {
            resolve({email:'An error occurs'});
          }
      )
    });
  };
}
```

Here is the way to configure the validator in this case:

```
ngOnInit(): any{
  this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    'email': ['',
      Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.emailValidator]),
      CustomValidators.createCheckUser(this.http)], // <-----
    'password': ['', Validators.minLength(8)]
  })
}
```

See this article (section "Asynchronous validation for fields") for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/